# cell phone input field on the fly to php

Tags: php, mysql

I will try to explain this the best way I can.

I have a page **cars.php** that displays results from a mysql table. Here is the php code that returns these results.

```
    <?php while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
    echo '<div class="items">';     
    echo "<a class='cars' href=\"item.php?id={$row1['id']}\"><img src={$row1['cars_img']} width='250px' height='250px'></a>";
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="caption">';   
    echo $row1['car_name'];
    echo '</div>'; 

    echo '<div class="send">';  
    echo "<a href=\"text.php?id={$row1['id']}\">Send</a>";
    echo '</div>';

?>
```

This returns a bunch of thumbnail images, captions, and a hyperlink "SEND" next to each result returned.

When I click SEND, it points to TEXT.PHP which sends a text message using a service called TextMagic. It's essentially returning results in php and uses a TextMagic include to communicate with the service. Here is the contents of TEXT.PHP...

```
<html>
<head>
  <?php include('textmagic-sms-api-php/TextMagicAPI.php');?>
</head>
                     <?php
                        //Establishing Connection with Server
                        $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "cars", "cars");

                        //Selecting Database
                        $db = mysql_select_db("cars", $connection);

                        ?>
                        <?php
                        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
                        $id = $_GET['id'];
                        $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_cars WHERE tbl_cars.id =  '$id'", $connection);                    

                            ?>   

<body>

<?php

$api = new TextMagicAPI(array(
    "username" => "my.username", 
    "password" => "password"
));
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) { 
$text = $row1['client_name'] . "-" . $row1['phone']



// Use this number for testing purposes. This is absolutely free.
$phones = array(17033005129);

$results = $api->send($text, $phones, true);

}}?>
</body>
</html>
```

The text message that gets sent contains the client name and phone number as you can see from the code...

```
$text = $row1['client_name'] . "-" . $row1['phone']
```

And it sends it to the phone number listed in the $phones variable

```
$phones = array(17033005129);
```

What I am trying to do *(that has been frustrating me to no end)* is instead of using the static phone number within the $phones variable, I would like the user to enter their phone number in an input field that the $phones variable will use.

So when someone clicks SEND, instead of just sending text to 17033005129, it pops up a windows or modal that asks user for their own cell phone number. Then the TEXT.php gets that number somehow and throws it in the $phones variable.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: how about just adding a form input box on the page ?

Comment: How can I do this if my page doesn't use a form. My cars.php currently uses < A HREF to send info to text.php  `code <a href=\"text.php?id={$row1['id']}\">Send</a> code`. If I create a textbox on my cars.php named "phone", how can I pass that value into text.php???

Comment: I played with GET which allows me to pass textbox value, but that requires a form submit action.